# Is each browser tab its own connection when using Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Say there are 5 open tabs in a single browser, and I am using Node.js and Socket.io. The client and server exchange packets to maintain (establish) communications.

Will connection with the client be lost if of one tab is closed?

How can I determine if the user closed the browser?

Comment: It appears that the disconnect method on server side is called after closing each tabs(pages) for current user. Is it correct? Why, if user is still online? For each page(tabs) create one stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, socket.io establishes a new connection with every tab. You're going to want to look into using session cookies to figure out which user the current socket.io connection is communicating with.